# What is the best way to make a database based test maker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, django, meteor

I am a teacher at a school and I am planning about making test-maker.
The blue-print for the application that I want to make is like this:

1. There is a database that stores information of questions.(fields: question, answer, topic, level, score)
2. You can add to the database by reading a csv file or a json file.
3. You can make a test using the data from the database based on a query.
4. You can style your test template as you like.
5. Other teachers(users) can log in and add to the database.

I have done some research on how to make this and thought about using python-django or maybe ruby on rails. But I still can't decide what the best choice would be. I feel that django is a bit more difficult than rails but python's numpy, pandas library might be useful when I look into more complicated data research in the future.
Someone told me that using node.js-meteor might be good because you only need to use one programming language.

I have experience in writing apps in VB and using SQL. 
I mainly use a mac.

It would be great if I could get some advice on how I should proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Django, but have used Rails.

Your app requirements are pretty simple and most web frameworks would be more than capable of creating it.

I personally would recommend using the framework you are most familiar with.

If I were tasked with creating the app I would use Rails or Padrino as I am familiar with them, however if you are not familiar with Rails, it may be confusing at first as it does a lot of 'magic' for you and you might find it difficult to connect the dots. Plus some of the ruby syntax may confuse you in the beginning, especially method calls without parenthesis.

That said, if you plan on learning a platform for use in future projects as well, Ruby and Rails is a great choice. Rails is a mature platform, has a gem for almost anything you can think of e.g. a login system, admin panel, payment processing etc and Ruby is a joy to code in.

Comment: Thank you very much Spidey. I will look into Ruby on Rails a little more. Can I ask one more question? When making the test, I would like to make it a txt data so I could print it out. Is Ruby a good choice for this?

Comment: You can do this with Ruby. However, when showing a newly created test in HTML, you can change the CSS so that it if more print friendly. For example a teacher creates a test. Once created, he/she clicks the print icon, which opens the same page with different CSS that strips all unnecessary graphics and widens the text to fill the width.

Comment: Thank you again, Spidey. I will start looking into Rail now and see what I can do.